# How to make a scoreboard with coarse and fine adjustment spinbuttons in Powerpoint

Tags: vba, powerpoint, activexobject

VBA novice and first time poster here.  Sorry if I make any newbie mistakes.

I'm a teacher and I'm trying to make a Jeopardy game in Powerpoint.  I'm trying to tackle the Daily Double wagering.  I want a slide that has the wager in a textbox, and can be adjusted by using either of TWO spinbuttons.  This is basically a COARSE and FINE adjustment.  I have the logic worked out, but I can't seem to change the .Value properties of the spinbuttons using VBA.  I tried

***Module 1***

```
Sub InitializeScoreBoard()
    ActivePresentation.Slides("ddWager").Shapes("SpinButton1").OLEFormat.Object.Value = 0
    ActivePresentation.Slides("ddWager").Shapes("SpinButton2").OLEFormat.Object.Value = 0
End Sub
```

***Slide 117***

```
Public Sub SpinButton1_Change() 'I changed to Public because I thought the spinbuttons were having trouble seeing each other or the code within the Sub's
    ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Slide.Shapes("wagerTextBox").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Me.SpinButton1.Value 'commands the textbox to display the spinbutton1's value as the spinbutton is manipulated
    ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Slide.Shapes("SpinButton2").OLEFormat.Object.Value = Me.SpinButton1.Value 'supposed to tie SpinButton2's .Value to SpinButton1's .Value
```

End Sub

```
Public Sub SpinButton2_Change() 'I changed to Public because I thought the spinbuttons were having trouble seeing each other or the code within the Sub's
    ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Slide.Shapes("wagerTextBox").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Me.SpinButton2.Value 'commands the textbox to display the spinbutton2's value as the spinbutton is manipulated
    ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Slide.Shapes("SpinButton1").OLEFormat.Object.Value = Me.SpinButton1.Value 'supposed to tie SpinButton1's .Value to SpinButton2's .Value
```

End Sub

Not only does this not work, but when I run the show and manipulate spinbutton1, it gives me a dialogue box that says "Could not set the Value Property. Invalid property value."  At first I thought this was a Data Type mismatch, so I tried using various CInt() and CStr() commands to try and find a match, to no avail.  Other experiments trying to set the .Value of a spinbutton have all failed.  I tried using the .ControlFormat object, but I suspect that only works for Excel, not PPT.  Any insight you all have would be appreciated.  If you don't want to address my specific problem, general advice about how to set the value of a spin button with VBA (in powerpoint) would be helpful, too.  Thanks!